# check if the value in a dict is not empty?

Tags: python

I have a dict `theaterinfo` like this :

```
 "Showtimes":{
        "New York": [
            {
                "Times": {}, 
                "theaterid": 61, 
            }
        ]
        "Ohio": [
            {
                "Times": {'2015-01-10',
                          '2015-01-11'}, 
                "theaterid": 1, 
            }
        ]
    }
```

How can I deal with that if `Times` in empty,don't print it out??

Comment: Don't print what out? The name of the theater (`"New York"`, `"Ohio"`)? Or the key/value pair `"Times": {}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over the `dict["Showtimes"]` items  then access the `dict` in the list using the `Times` key and check using an if which will return False for an empty dict.

```
d = {"Showtimes":{
        "New York": [
            {
                "Times": {},
                "theaterid": 61,
            }
        ],
        "Ohio": [
            {
                "Times": {'2015-01-10',
                          '2015-01-11'},
                "theaterid": 1,
            }
        ]
    }}

for k,v in d["Showtimes"].iteritems():
    if v[0]["Times"]:
       print(k,v)
('Ohio', [{'theaterid': 1, 'Times': set(['2015-01-10', '2015-01-11'])}])
```

One thing to be careful of is if you have a value like `0`, this will also return False so if you only want to check if the value is an empty dict use `if v[0]["Times"] != {}`

If you want to check all values of `Times` and only print the full dict if there are no empty `Times` values  you can use all which will short circuit on the first occurrence of an empty value:

```
if all(v[0]["Times"] for v in d["Showtimes"].itervalues()):
    print(d)
```

Or reverse the logic with any:

```
if not any(not v[0]["Times"] for v in d["Showtimes"].itervalues()):
    print(d)
```

If there is a chance a dict won't have a `Times` key use `v[0].get("Times",1)`

Comment: lol a downvote for the answer the actually answers the question

Comment: What is the value/difference in using `not any(not...` versus just `all`?

Comment: @HuuNguyen, I would use all in this case, I just added any as another example so if the OP wanted to avoid, say just an empty dict they could use `if not any(v[0]["Times"] == {} ...`

Answer (score 2):

An empty dictionary evaluates to a boolean `False` while a non-empty dict evaluates to `True`, so you can write

```
if my_dict['Times']:
    print(my_dict['Times'])
```

Comment: yes, but this errors out if there is no `my_dict['Times']` the proper way would be `my_dict.get('Times')`